# DjangoRestFramework with Oracle and no id field

Tags: django, python-3.x, oracle11g, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to get Django Rest Framework (3.6.4) running with a simple model.  However, the model does not contain an ID field so I'm getting

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-00904: "HCM_JOBS"."ID": invalid identifier
```

The PK is going to be a composite of three fields in the model.

I tried setting a custom id field in my serializer via

```
class HcmJobsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source="HcmJobs.position")

    class Meta:
        model = HcmJobs
        fields = '__all__'
```

but I still get the same ORA-00904 error from it trying to get an id field.

Most of what I've found on StackOverflow has been on how to deal with the id field, not how to deal with not having one.  I don't have control over the tables themselves so I can't add in an id field.

Any idea how I can use the framework without an ID field?

Comment: Turns out this had nothing to do with DRF.  My tables had to PK and that made Django balk.  I've talked with the table owners and they've marked the PK so I regenerated the models and the error stopped.